# What is the load/Capacity of req.session when using expressjs on node server ?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack

I Couldnt find the **capacity in terms of storage size** for maintaining data in express server session ?

My Intent is that I want to have emailid,some number variable, firstname, lastname etc when the user is in logged in state.. 
  So for instance , if we have max 1 lakh customers are in logged state , I have to maintain huge data in session that shouldnt get crashed by any chance..

Is it possible to use express SessionStore for such scenario ?? or I will have to go for any alternatives like Redis,MongoStore ??

But right now i am comfortable with express SessionStore...

Pls advice if i have to face any issues in future.. Also let me know **what is the demerits of using sessionstore** ?

Comment: Sounds like a good fit for Redis if you have enough memory.  Otherwise, mongo.

Comment: It turns out, 1 lakh is 100,000 See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh @hgoebl

Comment: What is wrong in keeping the session data in mongo?

Comment: Sample data for a single session will be 
{usermail : abc@gmail.com,
 balance_records:xx,
 days_pending:xx,
 id:xxxx,
 type:'xxxxx',
 date:'xx-xx-xx'} 

Similary i want to maintain thousands of similar JSON data in session when thousands of users are in logged state.. When each user   logs out , respective session data will be cleared...

 So can i go for Express SessionStore for maintaining the above volume of data..?